# Specified stream length is wrong. Fall back to reading stream until endstream

Tags: java, solr, pdfbox, apache-tika

I'm trying to send PDF documents for parsing using [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Extending_the_ExtractingRequestHandler). (Specifically I'm using [SolrNet](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet) but I don't think it is related to this problem).

However, for every PDF file I sent I get the following warning in the log (from Solr Admin):
[image]

According to what I have researched, this is happens with certain PDFs when read by PDFBox. I found a similar [bug report here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2381) which says to change the `pushbacksize`.
The problem is I'm using Solr 5.2.1 and have not been able to figure out how to configure this setting. Is there a way to configure Solr so I can index these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PDFs are broken. A PDF stream object looks like this:

```
4 0 obj
<<
/Length 34841
>>
stream
... content (which should have a length of 34841 bytes) ...
endstream
endobj
```

So if "endstream" doesn't appear at the expected offset, you get the message described. It means PDFBox tries a "Plan B"; if no further message is displayed, then the PDF will be processed. All you could do is to tell the creator of the PDF to work cleanly, i.e. to calculate the stream lengths properly. Or to avoid opening a PDF file in a "cheap" text editor and saving it.

The issue PDFBOX-2381 describes a different error, which is that the pushback buffer is too small.

Comment: Thanks. Would you say PDFBox is strictly conforming to the PDF spec? I haven't had issues with other PDF libraries before.

Comment: @JesseGood No; if PDFBox was "strictly" conforming to the PDF spec, the file would be refused. But this isn't an "issue": if there isn't a message after that, it means your file has been processed. Maybe the other libraries quietly process the file, or the log level was set differently.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I see now it is just a warning.